# CentOS 7 network setup

Tags: networking, linux

I am setting up a Pi3 B+ as a homeserver. Intended uses are running a Pi-Hole, using it as NFS share and to automate stuff like backups.

I decided to use CentOS for its reputation of running smooth and stable. I have quite some Linux experience, running Manjaro on my desktop, but I am a virgin in regards to CentOS and the network setup is quite confusing.

#### What is the relation between `NetworkManager`, `firewalld` and `iptables`?

I read `iptables` is slowly dying in favor of `nftables`. `firewalld` is a wrapper around `iptables`, but is a more modern choice and is propably continued as wrapper around `nftables`, even after the death if `iptables`. I also read that `firewalld` is dependent on `NetworkManager`. Neither do I know why, nor did `yum` stop me from uninstalling `NetworkManager` while `firewalld` was installed and running.

#### What is the current combination of tools to use?

I heard
[`NetworkManager` causing some issues](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50167/centos-7-on-raspberry-pi-3-disabling-networkmanager-service-and-enabling-network), which I ran into myself, fixed according to the answer in the linked question, but then managed to revitalize by trying to put `NetworkManager` to work again. Would I even need something like a network manager when not running in multiple networks? Are [those](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Network_managers) viable alternatives even on CentOS?
I am very inclined to use `firewalld` as a wrapper around `iptables`, is that possible without `NetworkManager`?

#### Additional information on use-case

Ideally, I would want to run a NFS share locally, and provide SSHFS service for remote (meaning not via LAN) access. Further, if everything runs as intended I would grant my other in the LAN access (looking at Kerberos for that). So I would like to have a convenient but flexible way of configuring the firewall and any further network configs surprising me on the way.

Comment: I have never used CentOS (like most on this site I find Raspbian the best match for the Pi). There is nothing Pi specific in this post - try unix.stackexchange.com